# Is commenting about funny title wording considered off-topic?

Tags: discussion, comments

I've commented [this question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/258362/does-shooting-people-make-them-dislike-me) after seeing the peculiar title, just to say how I appreciate this "tradition" on Arqade.

But today my comment was removed. I didn't know that commenting about funny titles wasn't allowed (anymore?). I used to see this kind of comments on old questions.

Was it heavily off-topic to require a deletion?

Note: This is not a complaint, just wanted to know if I did something wrong.

Comment: [This may provide some context](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/9956/hot-network-question-silly-title-comment-sanity?rq=1)

Comment: @TrentHawkins That's the worst case ever, but I see your point. Thank you.

Comment: @pinckerman Coincidentally, both are about questions by the same user.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They tend to get flagged and deleted as too chatty. Often we get many of these comments on each potentially amusing questions, and while we appreciate that the titles are often humorous out of context, the comments tend to stack up. Comments are second class citizens and generally prone to deletion if they aren't actually clarifying the post or anything like that.